# jQuery ready function loads only on refresh

Tags: jquery, image, fadein, document-ready

I'm trying to get all images to `fadeIn` on page load. However, this only happens when I refresh the page. When I click on a link to another page, it doesn't do anything. Here is my code:

custom.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
    jQuery('img').hide().fadeIn(300);
 });
```

head.php

```
<script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
```

I have checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234579/document-readyfunction-not-loading-unless-refreshed) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124706/jquery-fadein-image-after-it-is-loaded) but they both have the same solution as mine. I got the current code from [this thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/image-fade-on-load-solved#14737000002539675).

Comment: `When I click on a link to another page, it doesn't do anything` -- What other page? Does that code exist on that other page? is this ajax based page-loading? Is the path correct to the JS file when you travel to those other pages?

Comment: When I click on a relative link that goes to a different page in the same website it doesn't fade. Yes, the code exists on every page. No, it's not using ajax based page-loading. Yes, the path is always correct.

Comment: Please verify the code in question fires, using `alert/console.log('Working');`, once you've verified that, then you can localize your issue from there. You may want `$(window).load` if you're waiting until all images have resolved as well, as `$(document).ready` works whenever the HTML of the page has been read in it's entirety, without regard for scripts/images/objects being loaded.

Comment: And that other page has jquery included ?

Comment: If i had a guess to take, i would say the animation happen, but your imgs arent fully loaded. 300ms is short and the animation is probly done when image are loaded. Try Change `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()`

Comment: If the animation work on refresh, that's because your img are already cached.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, that worked. The fading effect was too fast to notice. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Well posted it as an answer..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i had a guess to take, i would say the animation happen, but your imgs arent fully loaded. 300ms is short and the animation is probly done when image are loaded. Try Change `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()`.

If the animation work on refresh, that's because your img are already cached.

Answer (score 0):

the ready method of jQuery trigger when the DOMis ready, no the Images. Every img is a separated request from the main page. If you have google chrome (another browsers have similar functionalities) you can inspect the page, and in the network tab you can see all the request your site does.

What you have to do is listen for the event when the img loads.
jQuery had a function for it (load: [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)) but is deprecated.

You should use on('load'), something like this:

```
$('document').on('load', function() {
   //Do the magic
})
```

I suggest you load the images already hided, and show them on load.

you can also use something like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { //Do magic }
img.src = "http://path/to/image.jpg";
```